# Nativescript update UI on ObservableArray push

Tags: nativescript

Playground link: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=VfEaFs&v=6

I have an ObservableArray in my view model, and want to always display the last element.

On loading the page, I push a new item on to the ObservableArray but the UI doesn't update. It always displays 3, I'm expecting 42.

Is it not possible to use a converter in this way? What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression reads `someNumbers, someNumbers | latest()` - meaning update view only when `someNumbers` attribute is changed. But you don't change the attribute here but manipulate data inside the array so the change detection do not happen at all.

You could do `someNumbers.length, someNumbers | latest()` instead, the length is updated whenever you push / pop array and right value will be updated on UI.